# How to unarchive object using NSKeyedUnarchiver?

Tags: swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, userdefaults

**I'm using this class: **

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var image: String
    
    init(name: String, image: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""
        image = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "image") as? String ?? ""
    }
    
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(image, forKey: "image")
    }
}
```

For **archiving**, i used this method:

```
if let savedData =  try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people, requireSecureCoding: false)
```

whrere **people** is Person class array [Person]

As for **unarchiving**, this method:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedTopLevelObjectWithData()
```

is deprecated... which method should i use now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now must tell the system what type you expect rather than simply unarchiving whatever is found:

```
try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: Person.self, from: savedData)
```

Comment: An error always occurred when i try do this. Error:  " requires Person class to conform from NSSecureCoding ". And when i conform to NSSecureCoding with supportSecureCoding to false. Then application is crashing.

Comment: You cannot conform to NSSecureCoding and the set `supportsSecureCoding` to false. "In addition, the class must override the getter for its supportsSecureCoding property to return true." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding  Non-secure coding is the thing that was deprecated. The replacement is secure coding.